# How can I apply a fadein effect to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create my whole html with JS. Here's an example:

```
function createBanner () {
    $('body').append(
      $('<div>')
      .attr('id',"banner")
      .attr('class',"banner")
      .append(
      ....
```

When the function is executed it creates the whole markup for the page.

How can I call createBanner with a "fadeIn" jQuery effect. The elements aren't initially in the page. That's why it's not possible to select them in the common way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the object of markup that needs to be appended, hide it using `.hide()`. then append it to body using `.appendTo()` along with `.fadeIn()` to give fade in effect:

```
 $('<div>').attr('id',"banner").attr('class',"banner").append(....)
      .hide()
        .appendTo("body")
          .fadeIn(500);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2d1bdLuz/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could try to hide it after your append(); and then fade it in.

Answer (score 1):

Quick way as below. you could bind this to an event.

```js
$(function(){
    var dv = $('<div>');
    $('body').append(dv.attr('id',"banner").attr('class',"banner").html("Some kind of content"));
    $('.banner').last().fadeIn(3000)

})
```

```css
.banner{
  display:none;
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```